# Differential Calculus Population Growth Modelling

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I require assistance with modelling population growth.

I have the initial function,

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP-AP^2$$

Through separation of variables, partial fraction decomposition, calculus and algebraic manipulations, I ended up with the following formula.

$$P(t)=\frac{{\omega}ke^{kt}}{1+{\omega}Ae^{kt}}$$

Where:

$${\omega}={\frac{P_0}{k-A{P_0}}}$$

$${P_0}=initial \ population$$

I am now trying to find the values of A and k so I can substitute them to find a function which will graph the change in population size with respect to time (t).

I have used the following information to find the value of $\omega$.

During 1961, the population is 11.4 (million). During 1971, the population is 14.5 (million).

From this, my initial $P_0$ value was 11.4 for when $t$ is equal to $0$; assuming 1961 is the initial population.

For $P$ which is LHS of the equation, I have made it equal to 14.5 with $t$ being 10; since it is 10 years away.

I cannot find the $k$ or $A$ value just by substituting these values into the equations.

There are too many unknown variables.

Am I missing something here?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, you have three unknowns and only two equations. Introducing the equation for $\omega$ makes it four unknowns and three equations.

Comment: @MattiP. Do you have any idea whether I am missing something here? Have you dealt with something like this before?

Comment: How many data pairs are known, $(0,11.4);(10, 14.5);...?$

Comment: I think that in its current form there is no unique solution. The values for $k$ and $A$ are whichever values fulfill
$$
\frac{ \left( \frac{11.4}{k-11.4A} \right)k e^{10k}}{1+ \left( \frac{11.4}{k-11.4A} \right)A e^{10k}} = 14.5
$$

Comment: @callculus I have around 5-6 data pairs; off the top of my head.

Comment: "off the top of my head"? Are you reading the values from a graph? Where do you get the data from?

Comment: @MattiP. Yeah, sorry. I have been given population data from 1961 to 2011. The population data is once every 10 years.

Comment: I would then consider calculating the derivative (and assume that it's of the quadratic form) - perhaps you can obtain the coefficients $k$ and $A$ from a least-squares approximation?

Comment: @MattiP. I'll try that. I'll have to research what least-squares approximation is first. I'm only a Grade 12 student barely scrapping by in my specialist mathematics class. Ha.